# Passing JSON as HTML element text

Tags: ajax, json, jquery

Would there be bad consequences from transporting JSON in HTML like this:

```
<div id="json" style="display: none;">{"foo": "bar"}</div>
```

assuming HTML chars such as `<` are escaped as `&lt;` in the element text?

The JSON could be strictly parsed:

```
var blah = $.parseJSON($('#json').html())
```

in a try/catch statement, for example. The rationale is to enable passing of JSON in Ajax'd HTML responses, when script tags are being stripped an **not** executed. An example would be Ajax requests made using the jQuery .load() [special selector syntax](http://api.jquery.com/load/#script-execution):

```
$('#here').load('some.html #fragment')
```

...which ditches all script tags and thus prevents the use of:

```
<script>var blah = {"foo":"bar"}</script>
```

I've seen JSON being passed around in HTML attributes, and I'd guess this is equivalent - w.r.t. weirdness, security, etc - but is far less readable due to all the additional quote-escaping.

Answer (score 2):

The natural way of passing JS data in HTML is through JavaScript code (if is a part of actual JavaScript code, like in the case of initial values/configuration) or by `data-` HTML5 attributes (whenever JS code is not necessary; always when data needs to be somehow attached to DOM elements).

In your example this would be probably the best:

```
<div id="json" style="display: none;"
    data-something="{&quot;foo&quot;:&quot;bar&quot;}">
</div>
```

but reorganize your data to actually follow HTML structure:

```
<div class="profile-container"
    data-profile="{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;John Doe&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:123}">
    ... profile 123 ...
</div>
<div class="profile-container"
    data-profile="{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Jane Doe&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:321}">
    ... profile 321 ...
</div>
```

(quoting should be done server-side, eg. using [PHP's `htmlspecialchars(...)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php), or [Python's `cgi.escape(..., True)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html#cgi.escape)).

And then you can obtain the data in one of multiple ways, eg. using [jQuery's `.data()` method](http://api.jquery.com/data/).

**EDIT:**

Yes, your approach with embedding JSON as content of HTML tags and hiding it using CSS styles has gotchas. As I said, if you want to pass data in HTML, the only "best practice" way is to attach it to one of HTML elements (you are kind-of doing it anyway, but you use CSS to hide it, while you can use **existing** solutions for passing JSON/data without affecting clients that could override your styles). The proof for one of disadvantages is here: http://jsfiddle.net/NY7Bs/ (data is passed both ways, but one simple external style overrides your inline styles and shows the content - not mentioning the influence on *semantics* of your document).

Comment: The question refers to a scenario in which JS is **not** executed on Ajax load. Also - in my particular case at least - there's no requirement to attach to particular DOM elements. I think the approach in the question is more readable (because less character escaping is required). But still wonder if it has any gotchas.

Comment: @StephanFowler: Yes, your approach has plenty of "_gotchas_": semantics, mess, ambiguity, ability to show it using CSS - to name few. Just look at one of the examples here: http://jsfiddle.net/NY7Bs/ My advice is: do not reinvent the wheel. If you want to pass data in HTML, you have to attach it to one or more of the elements, and you could use built-in HTML5 support (with backports) for data passed as JSON. And quoting is necessary for complex data (unless you will mix quotes, but I did not test it). No, really: use industry standard solutions.

Comment: Thanks Tadeck, I take on your comments. I'm now using a data-* attribute, which jQuery .data() helpfully parses if looks like JSON. The only downside is that the attribute val is rather unreadable after all the necessary char encoding - but otherwise I agree it's a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use the .ajax() function then, you would get only the string with the json. Then you could parse it as you suggested.

Comment: Perhaps the question wasn't clear. The scenario is when we're required to pass HTML fragments, and want to include JSON within the response, but are using the jQuery .load('url #selector') syntax, which doesn't execute script tags.

Comment: No, it was. I'm sorry I posted an answer, it's because i cannot comment for now. But I would like to understand in which situation this would be required.